# Error: cannot find symbol/class Firebase in android studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am following the firebase assistant and video tutorial. I am receiving an error and it says that (see picture below)[image: error]

Here is my code:

[image]

[image]

I had the same problems with `Button`, `EditText`, and `View`; but I resolved that by adding import statements. Is there any way import Firebase?

Comment: Just use Alt + enter  to import missing classes.

Comment: Oh I see! :) Let me try that. Thanks. I've never used Java for almost 6 years. hahaha!

Comment: Not working sir :(

Comment: Well, it's not java that is doing that, it's A-S (The IDE)

Comment: But, thanks. It is now working.

Comment: Oh! :D I'm so noob. Thanks sir. :)

Answer (score 2):

Just import `com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase`

Comment: Hi @RF_956 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

- Simply you goto `Firebase Console` and add your required `dependecies` like `com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.0` you have to add this line in your `app/build.gradle`
- make sure have to add `core dependency` in `app/build.gradle` which is   `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.0'`

---

```
android {
 // ...
}

dependencies {
// ...
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.0'
}

 // ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

---

- in your build.gradle you've to add this `snippet`

---

```
buildscript {
// ...
dependencies {
    // ...
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0' // google-services 
  plugin
   }
  }

    allprojects {
   // ...
   repositories {
    // ...
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
    }
    }
      }
```

---

## Happy to help you